# How to get MAC Adress on expo project react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, mac-address

***when i want to get mac adress using expo-NETWORK ,
it asks for *** "hundling promises"
code :
`
const ipAlert = async () => {
try {

```
      const ip = await Network.getMacAddressAsync('wlan0')()
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('That did not go well.')
  }
  };`
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getMacAddressAsync()` call returns a promise, which you need to handle like this:

```
Network.getMacAddressAsync()
        .then(macAddress => {
             console.log(macAddress)
         })
         .catch(error => console.log(error))
```